# What does "killing me softly" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

There is a song called "Killing Me Softly" by Roberta Flack.

What does that exactly mean?

Is it good or bad?

Is this song sad or the opposite?

Is she begging to be killed, because she is very sad and the death will finish her sadness?

Comment: Speaking as a native speaker, I have no idea.  Lyrics are weird.

Comment: There is a movie too, 'killing them softly'.

Comment: [Related](http://www.don-mclean.com/?p=310). [Also related](http://www.songfacts.com/detail.php?id=71). Song interpretation is often based on conjecture and rumor, and, for that reason, it's often considered off-topic: there's no way to get "THE **right** answer". That said, I think we can let this question stand, if we stick with how language can use words like "killing" in a poetic context, and how it might mean something good **or** bad. If this turns into a lengthy debate about the "correct" interpretation of one particular song, though, that would be considered off-topic.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because none of the questions can even be addressed without resort to LitCrit techniques. Briefly, so OP has an answer: It doesn't mean anything 'exactly': it's "symboliste", evocative. It's good and bad. It's sad and celebratory. No, she's not asking to be killed, she *is* being killed.

Comment: What @StoneyB said. FWIW, I'll just say this use of *kill = cause great emotional strain* (c.f. *"You're breaking me up!"*) isn't very uncommon. Unlike *kill = cause great amusement*, which is idiomatically commonplace in forms like *"That guy kills me!"* (c.f. *That guy **cracks me up!***)

Answer (score 1):

The word kill has several uses beyond "murder" or "put to death." Not all of them are negative; consider Def. 10 in [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/kill):

> **kill** (*v.*) to overcome with attraction, laughter, surprise, etc ⇒ *she was dressed to kill, his gags kill me*

The American Heritage and Wiktionary (both found on [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/kill)) phrase it this way:

> **kill** (*v.*) to make such a strong impression as to overcome (AH)
>   **kill** (*v.*) to amaze, exceed, stun, or otherwise incapacitate (Wikt.)

In *Killing Me Softly*, the singer (or lyricist) is talking about being overcome with emotion while watching another singer. Whether that emotion is joy, sorrow, lust, or some combination of moving emotions is up for interpretation. We do know that, as the musician strums, it resonates with the singer's pain, but whether that pain is alleviated or worsened isn't really explained. All we know is that the killing is happening *softly* – which could be a synonym for *gently*, or it could be referring to the singer's soft voice. I'd wager that the original composer intended for this three-word phrase to have a built-in oxymoron of sorts; some are bound to find it poetic, while others are bound to find it confusing.

I think we can agree on this, from an English perspective: a song can *kill* you with sorrow, or *kill* you with laughter. Someone's music can ease one's pain, or bring back painful memories. Music can affect the emotions in powerful ways. Perhaps the lyricist wanted to leave the lyrics vague so the song itself would resonate with a wider audience.

Comment: Oh, you made it just under the wire!

Comment: @snailboat - Yes, with 71 seconds to spare, I think. Though I agree with Stoney's comment, I still thought it was possible to analyze (and answer) the question from an ELL perspective.